# IBM Bluemix : Cant deploy dist to PaaS

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy the following application on Bluemix

https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager

to run it locally, all i have to do is

```
sbt clean dist
```

which creates `target\universal\kafka-manager-1.3.0.4.zip`
and

```
bin/kafka-manager
```

for bluemix deployment, here are the steps that i perform as per

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack

```
sbt clean dist

cf push KafkaManager -p target\universal\kafka-manager-1.3.0.4.zip -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
```

also,

manifest.yml is

```
—
applications:
name: KafkaManager
host: KafkaManager
memory: 512M
domain: <domainName>
```

Procfile is

```
web: bin/kafka-manager -Dhttp.port=$PORT
```

and here is the directory structure from where i am executing the cf push

[image: base dir]

but the build fails. here is the log message

```
2016-03-22T14:07:58.14-0400 [API/0]      OUT Created app with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:07:58.79-0400 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 ({"route"=>"4a976f5f-d975-4845-ad0a-4b88a5d45afd"})
2016-03-22T14:10:33.90-0400 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 ({"name"=>"KafkaManager", "buildpack"=>"https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git"})
2016-03-22T14:11:11.73-0400 [DEA/4]      OUT Got staging request for app with id 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:11:15.81-0400 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-03-22T14:11:17.38-0400 [STG/4]      OUT -----> Downloaded app package (65M)
2016-03-22T14:11:17.98-0400 [STG/0]      ERR     Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/java-buildpack'...
2016-03-22T14:11:22.67-0400 [STG/0]      OUT     -----> Java Buildpack Version: 9383db1 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#9383db1
2016-03-22T14:11:24.76-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_73 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_73.tar.gz (1.7s)
2016-03-22T14:11:26.31-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.5s)
2016-03-22T14:11:26.91-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 2.0.1_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/memory-calculator-2.0.1_RELEASE.tar.gz (0.6s)
2016-03-22T14:11:27.00-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Memory Settings: -Xms768M -XX:MetaspaceSize=104857K -Xss1M -Xmx768M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=104857K
2016-03-22T14:11:27.79-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Play Framework Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/auto-reconfiguration/auto-reconfiguration-1.10.0_RELEASE.jar (0.7s)
2016-03-22T14:11:49.09-0400 [STG/4]      OUT -----> Uploading droplet (108M)
2016-03-22T14:11:57.92-0400 [DEA/4]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:12:07.01-0400 [DEA/4]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:12:07.03-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"e34d4f2d-7c8c-4da1-8e20-6ef3c0b203f7", "instance"=>"be015488d886433a825456b8a4fd7129", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670327}
2016-03-22T14:12:07.03-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"e34d4f2d-7c8c-4da1-8e20-6ef3c0b203f7", "instance"=>"be015488d886433a825456b8a4fd7129", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670327}
2016-03-22T14:12:45.39-0400 [DEA/6]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR     Oops, cannot start the server.
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.85-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2016-03-22T14:12:52.86-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-22T14:12:52.96-0400 [DEA/6]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:12:52.99-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"e34d4f2d-7c8c-4da1-8e20-6ef3c0b203f7", "instance"=>"999b791f1beb456ca263b90030c8bc76", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670372}
2016-03-22T14:12:52.99-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"e34d4f2d-7c8c-4da1-8e20-6ef3c0b203f7", "instance"=>"999b791f1beb456ca263b90030c8bc76", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670372}
2016-03-22T14:13:45.38-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR     Oops, cannot start the server.
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.59-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2016-03-22T14:13:53.60-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-22T14:13:53.67-0400 [DEA/0]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:13:53.69-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"e34d4f2d-7c8c-4da1-8e20-6ef3c0b203f7", "instance"=>"ec5bf1431df94c59b2551a01a7ba8dcf", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670433}
2016-03-22T14:13:53.69-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"e34d4f2d-7c8c-4da1-8e20-6ef3c0b203f7", "instance"=>"ec5bf1431df94c59b2551a01a7ba8dcf", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670433}
2016-03-22T14:14:45.38-0400 [DEA/7]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR     Oops, cannot start the server.
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.62-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2016-03-22T14:14:51.63-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-22T14:14:51.71-0400 [DEA/7]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:14:51.72-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"e34d4f2d-7c8c-4da1-8e20-6ef3c0b203f7", "instance"=>"88c4a645e5eb4edc9f1683a205d41269", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670491}
2016-03-22T14:14:51.72-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"e34d4f2d-7c8c-4da1-8e20-6ef3c0b203f7", "instance"=>"88c4a645e5eb4edc9f1683a205d41269", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670491}
2016-03-22T14:15:44.70-0400 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 ({"name"=>"KafkaManager", "memory"=>512, "buildpack"=>"https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git", "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
2016-03-22T14:15:45.41-0400 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 ({"route"=>"012a5695-a7a2-4408-970b-f5b2cc6f2a5b"})
2016-03-22T14:16:22.40-0400 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2016-03-22T14:16:23.98-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Got staging request for app with id 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:16:29.24-0400 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-03-22T14:16:30.83-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloaded app package (65M)
2016-03-22T14:16:32.26-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (45M)
2016-03-22T14:16:33.15-0400 [STG/0]      ERR     Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/java-buildpack'...
2016-03-22T14:16:38.17-0400 [STG/0]      OUT     -----> Java Buildpack Version: 9383db1 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#9383db1
2016-03-22T14:16:38.63-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_73 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_73.tar.gz (found in cache)
2016-03-22T14:16:40.16-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.5s)
2016-03-22T14:16:40.27-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 2.0.1_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/memory-calculator-2.0.1_RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
2016-03-22T14:16:40.36-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Memory Settings: -Xss995K -Xmx382293K -XX:MetaspaceSize=64M -Xms382293K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64M
2016-03-22T14:16:40.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Play Framework Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/auto-reconfiguration/auto-reconfiguration-1.10.0_RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
2016-03-22T14:17:07.37-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Uploading droplet (108M)
2016-03-22T14:17:14.84-0400 [DEA/4]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:17:14.84-0400 [DEA/4]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:17:14.84-0400 [DEA/4]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:17:27.60-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR     Oops, cannot start the server.
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.19-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2016-03-22T14:17:38.21-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-22T14:17:38.28-0400 [DEA/0]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:17:38.30-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"4c16b37d50ec4f84ba5bf605ce168245", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670658}
2016-03-22T14:17:38.30-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"4c16b37d50ec4f84ba5bf605ce168245", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670658}
2016-03-22T14:17:45.30-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:17:45.30-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:17:45.30-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:18:01.74-0400 [DEA/6]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:18:01.74-0400 [DEA/6]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:18:01.75-0400 [DEA/6]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:18:45.41-0400 [DEA/1]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR     Oops, cannot start the server.
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.09-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2016-03-22T14:18:53.11-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-22T14:18:53.19-0400 [DEA/1]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:18:53.45-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"69b54075519e471f845710266a192952", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670733}
2016-03-22T14:18:53.46-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"69b54075519e471f845710266a192952", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670733}
2016-03-22T14:19:45.44-0400 [DEA/4]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR     Oops, cannot start the server.
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.74-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2016-03-22T14:19:55.77-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-22T14:19:55.87-0400 [DEA/4]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:19:55.89-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"0dd7326b327c4cbd94dc23ad05cd7dab", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670795}
2016-03-22T14:19:55.89-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"0dd7326b327c4cbd94dc23ad05cd7dab", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670795}
2016-03-22T14:19:55.96-0400 [DEA/7]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:19:55.96-0400 [DEA/7]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:19:55.96-0400 [DEA/7]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:20:45.39-0400 [DEA/2]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR     Oops, cannot start the server.
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.28-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2016-03-22T14:20:52.29-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-22T14:20:52.37-0400 [DEA/2]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:20:52.39-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"0514086165b441dfb2f7a1bdc46bc42f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670852}
2016-03-22T14:20:52.40-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"0514086165b441dfb2f7a1bdc46bc42f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670852}
2016-03-22T14:22:30.50-0400 [DEA/7]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR     Oops, cannot start the server.
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:131)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:45)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.82-0400 [App/0]      ERR    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2016-03-22T14:22:36.83-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-22T14:22:36.92-0400 [DEA/7]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-22T14:22:36.93-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"411a0d25c9e04b859d92a311054566da", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670956}
2016-03-22T14:22:36.93-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2", "version"=>"d74e7e4f-7a23-456b-8890-9fd8858fbe2d", "instance"=>"411a0d25c9e04b859d92a311054566da", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>255, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458670956}
2016-03-22T14:22:45.64-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:22:45.64-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
2016-03-22T14:22:45.64-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 3a0a2af2-0ad4-42bf-8c06-b7bf4dad01c2
```

so the main error is

```
ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
```

which in turn causes

```
ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

i even tried it with Bluemix's built in Liberty Service but i still get the error.

**Edit**

I looked at

https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/issues/192

and hence changed my Procfile to

```
web: bin/kafka-manager -Dhttp.port=$PORT -Dpidfile.path=/tmp/kafka-manager.pid
```

but i still get

```
ERR java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/run/${{app_name}}.pid (Permission denied)
```

Is the Procfile command not executing?

Questions:

1. Is my setup correct?
2. Is this the correct way to deploy this app on Bluemix?
3. Would it be better if i just unzip the file and do a cf push from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i did it

1. Unzip the dist
2. Change the application.ini as
   -Dpidfile.path=/tmp/$app_name.pid
3. Create a Procfile that has
   web: bin/kafka-manager -Dhttp.port=$PORT
4. Create a user defined environment variable in bluemix as

JAVA_HOME= /home/vcap/app/.java/jre

Without this, the Kafka Manager does not detect Java.The Liberty buildpack sets this environment variable, but it is only exposed to the Java process running on Liberty. Since Kafka Manager application runs its own JRE it will not see it (thus will have to set it manually).

5. Creating a bluemix app with Java Liberty service
6. cf push from the directory where the dist was unzipped

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the configuration file takes precedence over the command line argument, so I changed the path file in the configuration file and the application was successfully deployed.

Edit `dist/conf/application.ini` and change it like this:

```
-Dpidfile.path=/tmp/${{app_name}}.pid
```

Run `sbt clean dist` again to create a new zip file.

Finally run the `cf push` command to redeploy your application.